# Bootstrap Tour on Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, bootstrap

How would you go about putting one of these:
http://bootstraptour.com/

on you Joomla 3 site?

Should I make a module? Modify my template?

How would you do it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with editing your template, that is exactly what templates are for; modifying the front-end output.

Comment: Is this a reply to my answer in regards to editing the template being a core hack? It should be a comment as it's does not really answers the OP's question. None the less, editing the template **can** be done, however lets say you make changes to a template index.php file and the developer of the template releases an update, what do you do? Install the update and make all those changes again? Or do you simply never update your template again? Template are to output the frontend display. Top modify the output, Template Overrides should be applied

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would not suggest editing your template as it's considered a core hack. Should you ever update your template to a newer version then you changes will be overridden. Instead I would suggest [developing a plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Plugin_Development). This might however take some time, especially if you've never developed a plugin before. As an alternative, I've found 2 extensions for this exact feature:

- [WebSite Tour Guide](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/miscellaneous/tutorials/22169) ($10)
- [Easy Tour](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/miscellaneous/tutorials/26119) ($12.23)

Both **are** commercial (prices shown above). Unfortunately I did not find any free extensions on the JED site but one of the above might be worth the money if your under a tight deadline or do not feel confident enough with plugin development.

Hope this helps